# What is the best way of creating a unique identifier name in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I want to create a check constraint on several thousand columns in a database, but all constraints needs a name that is unique in the database. I wanted to use a guid, but because of limitations in Oracle, the name can't be longer than 30 characters.

Here is an example of the syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable
(
    col1 DATE 
        DEFAULT to_date('19000101', 'yyyymmdd') 
        CONSTRAINT unique_name_needed CHECK(col1 = TRUNC(col1)) 
        NOT NULL
)
```

Comment: Simply don't specify a name. Oracle will generate one for you.

Comment: some Naming standard, including table name(atleast first few characters) in constraint name appended with numbers. I used to have this, so using the name, I can identify to which table it is!

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name. I actually tried just removing the name, but reading your comment, I realized that I also had to remove the 'constraint' keyword. Thanx. But I still hope someone comes up with a good answer. I also need names for temporary table names, etc.

Comment: Maheswaran: We tried your suggestion, but eventually got dupicates. Current approach is a <os pid><db pid><seq num> combo, but I was hoping it didn't have to be this complicated.

Comment: A naming convention shouldn't be based on something out of your control like O/S process IDs. Maheswaran meant something like `mytable_ck_col1`, where `ck` is the constraint type. You shouldn't be creating these things on the fly, and anything you need to be able to refer to later should have a predictable name. Temporary tables in Oracle are not (usually) created when needed, they are permanent data dictionary objects that use temporary storage, so they should also have fixed, predictable names - so your code knows what they're called. Otherwise you'd have to use dynamic SQL for them.

Comment: The problem with a naming convention involving table and/or column name, is that both of these names can themselves be 30 long, so you have to choose how much of the name you want to pick, which again can lead to duplicates (as it did for us).

Comment: Indeed, but if you can't avoid long object/column names, you have to be careful about how you abbreviate them - not just always use the first 10 chars, for example. It's useful if you, as a developer or DBA, can interpret the abbreviated name to have a good idea what it's doing, without having to refer back to `user_constraints` etc. As long as your abbreviation lets you do that it doesn't really matter how you achieve it. But this is a reason to avoid unnecessarily long base names where possible.

Answer (score 1):

We use a 3 letter short name for every table. These three letters we use to name our constraints. So the short name for mytable could be mtb.

Constraint names are then:

```
Primary: mtb_pk
Unique: mtb_uk
Foreign: mtb_otb_fk  where otb is the short name of the other table.
```

The trick of course is to come up with unique short names for every table.